# Skip top N lines in snowflake load

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My actual data in csv extracts starts from line 10. How can I skip top few lines in snowflake load using copy or any other utility. Do we have anything similar to SKIP_HEADER ?

I have files on S3 and its my stage. I would be creating a snowpipe later on this datasource.

Answer (score 3):

yes there is a skip_header option for CSV, allowing you to skip a specified number of rows, when defining a file format. Please have a look here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv

So you create a file format associated with the csv files you have in mind and then use this when calling the copy commands.